# Algorithms by Sedgewick & Wayne, Exercise 1.2.3

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, geometry

Algorithms by Sedgewick & Wayne, Exercise 1.2.3:

> Write an [`Interval2D`](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/Interval2D.java.html) client that takes command-line arguments `N`,
>   `min`, and `max` and generates `N` random 2D intervals whose width and
>   height are uniformly distributed between `min` and `max` in the unit
>   square. Draw them on `StdDraw` and print the number of pairs of
>   intervals that intersect and the number of intervals that are
>   contained in one another.

Interval2D exposes the following API:

```
Interval2D(Interval1D x, Interval1D y)
boolean intersects(Interval2D)
boolean contains(Point2D)
double area()
void draw()
```

Is it possible to check whether one `Interval2D` is contained in another using only these methods?

Answer (score 1):

A) To understand the situation:

Definition of the 2D intervals A and B in terms of 1D intervals:

```
 A = Ixa x Iya = [x1a, x2a] x [y1a, y2a]
 B = Ixb x Iyb = [x1b, x2b] x [y1b, y2b]
```

Then

```
 A is contained in B, iff 
 Ixa = [x1a, x2a] is contained in Ixb [x1b, x2b] and
 Iya = [y1a, y2a] is contained in Iyb = [y1b, y2b].
```

Using

```
 I1 = [a, b] is contained in I2 = [c, d] iff c <= a and b <= d.
```

This is similar to the implementation of the intersect methods in Interval2D (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/Interval2D.java.html) and Intervall1D (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/Interval1D.java.html) only that they test for the logical inverse of the conditions.

B) Now to your methods:

The contains(Point2D) should allow to do the test, if you check the lower left (x1a, y1a) and upper right (x2a, y2a) points:

```
 A is contained in B, iff B contains (x1a, y1a) and B contains (x2a, y2a).
```

The ugly thing is that while Interval1D has getters to access the private left and right coordinates, Interval2D has none to access it's private x and y (one dimensional) intervals.
You could parse them from its toString() output, but that is ugly and too much work.
Creating some super class

```
public class Rect {
  public Interval1D x;
  public Interval1D y;
  public Interval2D r;
  Rect(Interval1D px, Interval1D py) {
    x = px;
    y = py;
    r = new Interval2D(px, py);
  }
  public boolean contains(Rect that) {
    if (!this.r.contains(new Point2D(that.x.left(), that.y.left()))) return false;
    if (!this.r.contains(new Point2D(that.x.right(), that.y.right()))) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

and using it is just ugly.

Comment: So in affect, your answer is NO. We need to make use of other methods and private fields of the Interval2D class which may not be exposed by the API.

Comment: I think you are right, I would need access to the corner points of the Interval2D. And it doesn't show up in the API list.

Comment: I rewrote the answer to use the super class approach (storing x and y intervals in parallel to the 2D interval and providing a contains method for it).

Answer (score 1):

You might use methods left() and right() in Interval1D, in advance saving them during the creation of 2D intervals.

I did it like that

```
    int intersect = 0;
    int contain = 0;    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (arr2D[i].intersects(arr2D[j])){
                intersect++;
            }
            if ( (arrX[i].left() <= arrX[j].left() && arrX[i].right() >= arrX[j].right())
                && (arrY[i].left() <= arrY[j].left() && arrY[i].right() >= arrY[j].right())) {
                contain++;
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes much more sense to check for intersection using the upper and lower bounds of the interval. Theoretically it should be possible to use only the methods listed, but doing so efficiently may be tricky. If Interval A contains Interval b, then every point in B is also in A. We could therefore iterate over every point (if the coordinate system is based on int and not double) and check this condition.
If we are faced with doubles, then a modified technique could be used to generate a contains method that will function correctly with high probability.

```
//Iterate over some subset of points.
if(b.contains(pointP) && !a.contains(pointP))
   return false;
```

The trick is to find the right subset. But I think an algorithm guaranteed to always be correct is MUCH harder. Consider a one dimensional case. If interval `A = (0.5,Math.PI/6)` and `B = [0.4,Math.PI/6]`. It's obvious that B contains A but none of those methods can help us see that they both have the same right endpoint but B **includes** that point while A does not.
How can those methods help us differential that example from this one:

`A = (0.5,Math.PI/6]` and `B = [0.4,Math.PI/6)`
Now there is exactly one point that needs to be chosen to show that B does not contain A: `Math.PI/6`
This leads me to feel that such an algorithm is next to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here:

```
package exercise.chapter2.section2;

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Interval1D;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Interval2D;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

public class Ex1_2_03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double min = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double max = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        MyInterval2D[] boxes = new MyInterval2D[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            double width = StdRandom.uniform(min, max);
            double height = StdRandom.uniform(min, max);

            double xlo = StdRandom.uniform(width, 1.0 - width);
            double xhi = xlo + width;
            double ylo = StdRandom.uniform(height, 1.0 - height);
            double yhi = ylo + height;

            boxes[i] = new MyInterval2D(new Interval1D(xlo, xhi), new Interval1D(ylo, yhi));
            boxes[i].draw();            
        }

        int cintersects = 0;
        int ccontained = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (boxes[i].intersects(boxes[j])) {
                    cintersects++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            boxes[i].draw();
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (i != j && boxes[j].contains(boxes[i])) {
                    ccontained++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        StdOut.println(cintersects);
        StdOut.println(ccontained);
    }

}

class MyInterval2D extends Interval2D {
    private Interval1D xint;
    private Interval1D yint;

    public MyInterval2D(Interval1D xint, Interval1D yint) {
        super(xint, yint);
        this.xint = xint;
        this.yint = yint;
    }

    public boolean contains(MyInterval2D box) {
        if (xint.contains(box.xint.min()) && xint.contains(box.xint.max()) && yint.contains(box.yint.min()) && yint.contains(box.yint.max())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```